# Neutrino oscillations and neutrino mass measurement

Tags: particle-physics, mass, oscillators, neutrinos

At the KIT they have been measuring the mass of the electron neutrino with a huge spectrometer (i.e. they make an enormous effort) and already published limits on the highest possible electron neutrino mass (it is already less than $1$eV). How is this compatible with neutrino oscillations? The electron neutrino flavor state is a mixture of at least 2 mass eigenstates:

$$| \overline{\nu_e} \rangle = \cos\theta | \nu_1\rangle + \sin \theta |\nu_2\rangle $$

where $| \nu_1\rangle$ is the first mass eigenstate and $|\nu_2\rangle $ is the second mass eigenstate. I assume that the mass of both is significantly different.
$|\overline{\nu_e}\rangle$ is the electron neutrino flavor eigenstate. As far as I understand the mass of the flavor eigenstate is not known and upon measurement it would project on one of the 2 possible mass eigenstates. So what are they measuring actually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking about the [KATRIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KATRIN) tritium beta decay experiment, they are measuring the endpoint of the product electron spectrum in
$$
^3_1H \to ^3_2{He^+} + {e^-} + \bar{\nu}_e,
$$
whose half-life is 12ish years.

But, as you observe, $\bar{\nu}_e$ has no well-defined mass, since it is not a mass eigenstate, only a convenient shorthand for the superposition of states coupling to the electron. So there are three possible decays, to $\bar\nu_1,\bar\nu_2,\bar\nu_3$, not observed directly, but limited in the maximum energy/momentum they may fly away with, and thus constraining the maximum energy of the electron momentum measured. (There is an additional complication that $\bar{\nu}_e$ overlaps with the heaviest
$\bar{\nu}_3$ only very little, but no mind.)

The actual composite quantity measured is an "effective"  incoherent average quantity,
$$
(m^{eff}_{\nu_e})^2= \sum_{i=1}^3 m_i^2|U_{ei}|^2,
$$
pulled up by the $\bar{\nu}_3$ in the normal hierarchy, but whose influence  is diminished by the smallness of the corresponding PMNS *U* mixing element ($|U_{e3}|^2$~2%). After elaborate analysis, they conclude what an upper bound for it might be.

There are no oscillations involved here!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So they measure $m^{eff}_{\overline{\nu}_e}$ ? If this is the case, although they claim that the measurement is important for cosmology (& particle physics), does it help to know this very special quantity if actually the real mass $m_{\overline{\nu}_e}$ is needed for this?

Comment: The electron anti neutrino has no mass! But the mass of the 3rd  (heaviest) eigenstate is important for cosmology…

Comment: Sorry, I meant $m_{\nu_1}$. If $m_{\nu_3}$ is the most important quantity to know, how this is related to $m^{eff}_{\nu_e}$ ? And how many parameters are involved in this which also have to be known with a sufficient precision?

Comment: I was thinking of the normal hierarchy, by now all but established, so the heaviest is $\nu_3$. I think the incoherent average measured limits the precision quite a bit, and there are lots of parameters and other experimental input (from oscillation experiments) involved. But I really haven't looked into their [papers](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-021-01463-1); maybe you have or can. I am a mere theorist...

Comment: Cosmology [bounds](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2020/09/aa33910-18/aa33910-18.html)   another, complementary, quantity, $\sum_i m_{\nu_i}$, dominated by the heaviest $\nu_3$...

Comment: ... and once the highest mass is known, the others are too, since the mass differences are known from neutrino oscillation experiments...

Comment: I like the answe, but the statement "has no mass" seems open for interpretation if taken out of context, as far as I understand you mean "has no well-defined mass" (since it is a superposition and thus the mass question doesn't make sense) - but it could be confused with "has a zero mass".

Comment: @Hans Olsson. Thanks, fixed it; it never crossed my mind neutrino-gazers would be confused....